# Threading issues with > 30 threads. CPU scales non-linearly

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having some trouble with my C# application.

I made sure threads do not access any resources outside themselves.

Now I have threadpool thread that makes a tcp connection, creates the thread objects and runs, with 1 thread performance is great.  With 50 threads it seems the same, maybe 5-10% slower, CPU 10-20%.  With 100 threads, the CPU usage goes from 10-20% to 70-99%.

One of our developers said that windows threads suck compared to linux thread and the context switching is incurring huge penalties. He proposes to create multiplexing with 4-8 core threads running all the instances.

But I thought problems like this start happening once you have 1000+ threads.  Can anyone comment with some good sources to read more about this topic, and about thread / cpu performance and correct practices?

---

EDIT: OK Many answers seem a little off point because some assumptions are being made so I will add some extra points:

```
 Running 3 applications with 50 threads at 10-20% cpu usage  makes them all use that much. 30-60% CPU usage total.
 Running 1 application with 150 threads makes it cap cpu at 70-99%.
```

This is what i mean by threads not scaling.

Comment: It's not that Windows threads suck in comparison to POSIX threads it's that you're simply trying to do more things than your CPU can physically do at any one time. It's obvious that things are going to start slowing down and threads thus having a negative effect.

Comment: How many cores do you have? You can only run one thread per core at a time.

Comment: it is 2 physical cores 4 threads.  Its just I understand that threads dont scale linearly, but to scale so poorly made me puzzled and curious..

Comment: But it's not scaling poorly, 100 threads when you can only physically process 4 (well, 2 in reality ignoring the HT magic) is a lot to ask. It's also dependant on what you're doing, if they're all performing intensive operations or even just *any* actual work, then I'm not sure how you could expect a benefit.

Comment: Their performing intensive operations in spikes, based on what the tcp stream sends them to do.  I do not expect the operation to complete faster, each thread is a copy of the other, they all do the same task.  Im just puzzled why they are scaling so poorly.

Comment: Ignoring the threading aspect here, I'd suggest letting the OS handle your blocking rather than a custom thread (I assume you're looping on a read?). Use either the `async` provision or the older `Begin`/`End` async methods on reading which will alleviate the need for your own threads entirely.

Comment: Its all async at the core. The threads are very good on performance, we ran it weeks under profilers.  Pretty much got rid of everything "reasonable" to rid of and optimized the rest. 
The async listener on each thread ques up a ConcurrentDictionary of Messages, then the same thread processes them in a while(messageavailable())  with a signalwait(15) at the top.   Again tho, this is not relevent because the threads are non-locking with any objects outside themselves.  so they should scale no?

Comment: The secret of any program that uses lots of TCP connections is to use **no** threads.  Strongly enabled by .NET with its ability to grab a TP thread only when an I/O completion occurs.  It is entirely unclear why you think you have to start so many threads.

Comment: We are thinking of switching to 4-8 threads.  Its just that I guess the better example would be if you had a thread that does for(1m)List.Add(x);  while(true) thread.sleep(15) for(10000)List.Contains(x);  

Now this runs at 1% cpu usage lets say. You * it by 30.  so the CPU usage should be 30% +/- 5% context switching.  now *50 should be 50%+/-10%.   but in this case,  its scaling exponentially so quickly. Why?

Comment: @HansPassant: "No threads" is a bit misleading. You're still using threads to wait for IO Completion. "A few threads as possible" is a better way to phrase that.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on my comment..

It's not that Windows threads "suck" in comparison to POSIX threads it's just that you're trying to do more things than your CPU can physically handle at a time. CPU Usage is not particularly a relevant performance indicator that you should be looking at here.

If your CPU has 4 cores, your optimum amount of constantly-running threads is 4. Any more and performance degradation is going to happen as yes, context switching will have a performance impact as it tries to process through the threads simultaneously with only 1 resource.

Think of your threads as giant stacks of books on your table, you've got to knock each individual book off the top of each stack and you want them all doing as fast as you can. You've got 4 of these book stacks (threads) but only 2 arms (cores), how do you do it? The most likely option is to alternate which stack you knock books off each time, so there's no real performance benefit as the time taken for a single stack is going to take as long as any other.

The only time when this would differ is if you're running a blocking (ie. waiting for I/O) operation and your threads are idle. In this idle time your cores are free to work on another thread which can give a perceived performance benefit. Of course, when the resource that your other thread is waiting for becomes available you're back in the same situation you are in currently.

Comment: Yes but, if 50 threads run at 10-20%.  then 100 should run at 20-40% +/- 10% no?  Since its still using the same 4 cores except now its working twice+ as hard

Comment: As I said, CPU usage is not a real performance indicator that you should be looking at here. The context switching is probably the only thing that you're really seeing in "usage", and when you can't process instructions quickly enough as a processor you're going to be non-linearly showing spikes in CPU usage as you simply couldn't keep up with demand, it's not something you could show as a % of usage on the chip.

Comment: edited the main problem with more details. Its not a CPU usage problem, because running 3 instances at 50 threads each uses much less CPU then one with 150.